# Ruby Send Method, iterating as symbols instead of strings

Tags: ruby

I was reading ruby-docs on #send and saw that it took :symbols.

Does that mean that this code (assuming attr_accessors are set for attributes keys):

```
def initialize(attributes = {})
  attributes.each do |k,v|
    self.send("#{k}=", value)
  end
end
```

could be re-written as:

```
def initialize(attributes = {})
  attributes.each do |k,v|
    self.send(:k, value)
  end
end
```

or is that not equivalent?  And just curious - if it's not the same, is there cleaner way to do the original code using symbols?

Comment: Have you tried it? Run it through IRB and see what you get

Comment: I don't see how the second method is any cleaner. Also it won't work as :k is not defined. adding a `:` in front does not convert a variable to a symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, the two versions are not equivalent. The first one will call a method whose name is based on the content of the variable `k`. In the second version, the variable `k` is never used, it will simply call the method `k` over and over and over again.

IOW: the first version will call a *different* method on each iteration of the loop, the second one will call the *same* method on every iteration of the loop.

You can, of course, use symbols in exactly the same way you use strings here:

```
def initialize(attributes = {})
  attributes.each do |k,v|
    self.send(:"#{k}=", value)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`send` can take in both `symbol` and `string`

your can rewrite the method as

```
def initialize(attributes = {})
  attributes.each do |k,v|
    self.send("#{k}=".to_sym, value)
  end
end
```

Comment: `to_sym` is not needed, as the string is sufficient, and will actually consume memory rather than save it.

Comment: I agree. But that was to answer the question of OP.

Comment: Ok so you're saying just putting ':k' would not be the same? Thanks, will mark as answered once I know that.  Would be nice to know why too! Thanks.